# bluemix composer.json php update

Tags: php, composer-php, ibm-cloud

I am trying to set up sendgrid within bluemix to be able to send emails i followed the docs where the explain how to do this. This is what they say :

```
Installation

Add SendGrid to your composer.json file. If you are not using Composer, you should be. It's an excellent way to manage dependencies in your PHP application.

{  
  "require": {
    "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~4.0"
  }
}
Then at the top of your PHP script require the autoloader:

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

I added the line to my composer.json. But i am not getting any new files. how can i tell the composer to update/install the new library.

Answer (score 3):

When you push your app or restage it, Bluemix read the composer.json file and install all dependencies automatically.

Infact when you push an application you can read this output:

```
 **Loading composer repositories with package information**
       Installing dependencies from lock file
         - Installing twig/twig (v1.16.0)
           Downloading: 100%
         - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.5.4)
           Downloading: 100%
```

Remember that if you want to force bluemix to download dependencies after changing you have to issue this command:

```
cf restage APP_NAME
```

Comment: it says Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

Comment: Then you should do that locally and push the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files again. If you think that the lock file is up-to-date and only the hash differs, you can run `composer update --lock` to only update the hash in the lock file.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your composer file and run:

`composer update`

from the command line in the same directory as your `composer.json`.

You may also do:

`composer require sendgrid/sendgrid`

In the same directory and it will automatically install the package and it's dependencies and add the relevant require to you `composer.json`

Comment: I am not working locally i am working online in the devOps bluemix environment

Comment: composer requires you to run it from the command line, so you will need to log in via ssh, install composer and run composer update.

Comment: I don't use bluemix, however, I did  take a quick look and it seems that you won't be able to do this via ssh on their system. This article, may help you: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/06/17/getting-started-laravel-bluemix It is specifically for laravel, but laravel relies heavily on composer, so you should be able to pull out the info on how composer works in this environment.